How to propagate KeyboardInterrupt to multiprocessing Pool workers and gracefully exit?
I am using the multiprocessing.Pool in Python to parallelize a task that requires entering and exiting a context manager for each item in the workload. I want to ensure that when a KeyboardInterrupt occurs, the program gracefully exits by allowing each worker process to complete the exit method of its context manager by propagating the interruption (or something like that).
Here is a simple code snippet to illustrate my thoughts:
class MyContext:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print(f'Entering context {self.name}')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print(f'Exiting context {self.name}')
        time.sleep(5)
        print(f'Exited context {self.name}')


def process_name(name):
    with MyContext(name):
        print(f'Processing {name}')
        time.sleep(100)
        print(f'Finished {name}')


names = ['Alice', 'Bob']

with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as pool:
    pool.map(process_name, names)

Here is the result I expect:
Entering context Alice
Processing Alice
Entering context Bob
Processing Bob
^CExiting context Alice
Exiting context Bob
Exited context Alice
Exited context Bob
KeyboardInterrupt (maybe multiple times)

Here is the actual output:
Entering context Alice
Processing Alice
Entering context Bob
Processing Bob
^CExiting context Alice
Exiting context Bob
KeyboardInterrupt

The context manager's exit method is called, but it doesn't finish before the program crashes. What should I change to make it work as intended?
EDIT:
If there are reamaining tasks, I don't want the pool to keep mapping. So if I set the number of threads to 1, I don't want to get this:
Entering context Alice
Processing Alice
^CExiting context Alice, exc_type = <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>
Exited context Alice
Entering context Bob
Processing Bob
Finished Bob
Exiting context Bob, exc_type = None
Exited context Bob

but simply this:
Entering context Alice
Processing Alice
^CExiting context Alice, exc_type = <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>
Exited context Alice


Get rid of one of your tags (I suggest pool) and instead tag your question with the platform you are running on (Windows? Linux? Something else?). This is supposed to be done whenever a multiprocessing question is posted but is particularly important for your specific question. Also, post a [mre].

@Booboo, this is exactly what my snipet is... I tried it on couple of machines with different versions, same result.

The point is that the actual solution could be platform-dependent. So you should specify whatever platforms you actually need this to run on, preferably as a tag. Also, I do not see any multiprocessing-related code in your post.

@Booboo, you are right, I pasted the wrong snippet. My bad, I edited the snippet and the tag. So I made it linux cause this is the os I'll use it the most on but I got the same result with windows. Also, if I can get a solution for both it would be better.

Update
Based on your updated question, this is my updated answer. Now the main process has to handle a keyboard interrupt. However, if it uses the multiprocessing.pool.map method the interrupt will not be handled until the map function completes, which will be only after all submitted tasks are executed. This is not what you want and so we cannot use the map method. Instead we use the map_async method and loop testing whether it has completed. Even so, the interrupt won't be handled until the statement result = async_result.get(0) completes assuming that is the statement being executed by the main process when the interrupt occurs. In this case there could be a slight delay between the interrupt occurring and the pool terminated, which occurs automatically when the with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as pool: block is exited. So you will not see the __exit__ method executing the print(f'Exited context {self.name}') statement, which only occurs 5 seconds after prior message is output and the pool will have been terminated long before then.
import multiprocessing
import time
import signal

class MyContext:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print(f'Entering context {self.name}')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print(f'Exiting context {self.name}, exc_type = {exc_type}')
        time.sleep(5)
        print(f'Exited context {self.name}')
        # We need this to cause the with statement to suppress the exception
        # and continue execution with the statement immediately
        # following the with statement:
        return True

def process_name(name):
    with MyContext(name):
        print(f'Processing {name}')
        time.sleep(100)
        print(f'Finished {name}')

names = ['Alice', 'Bob']

# Not optional for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as pool:
            async_result = pool.map_async(process_name, names)
            while True:
                try:
                    result = async_result.get(0)
                except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
                    pass
                else:
                    break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('The pool and all tasks not currently executing have been terminated.')

    ... # Any additional code
    print('I am additional code.')

Prints:
Entering context Alice
Processing Alice
^CExiting context Alice, exc_type = <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>
The pool and all tasks not currently executing have been terminated.
I am additional code.

Update 2
The previous update terminated the pool guaranteeing that tasks on the pool's input queue will never run. But as a side effect, code in the method __exit__ might not complete. So if we cannot terminate the pool for that reason, there has to be a mechanism to effectively prevent tasks that haven't started executing from running. The only way I see to do that is to set an abort flag to True on a keyboard interrupt and every task when it starts running  will initially check the flag and if it is set, will immediately return. If the MyContext context manager is already running when the exception has occured, it will be handled by __exit__, which will check to see if a KeyboardInterrupt has occurred and will prevent the propagation of the exception.
import multiprocessing
import time
import signal

def init_pool():
    global abort_flag

    def set_abort(*args):
        """Executed when Ctrl-C has been entered.
        We set the global abort_flag so that tasks waiting to run will
        immediately terminate when started. We then re-raise the exception
        so that it will be handled by MyContext.__exit__.
        """

        global abort_flag

        abort_flag = True
        raise KeyboardInterrupt()

    abort_flag = False
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, set_abort)

class MyContext:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print(f'Entering context {self.name}')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print(f'Exiting context {self.name}')
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f'Exited context {self.name}')
        # Return True to supress exception
        return exc_type is KeyboardInterrupt

def process_name(name):
    if abort_flag:   # Should we abort?
        return  # Perform no processing

    with MyContext(name):
        print(f'Processing {name}')
        time.sleep(100)
        print(f'Finished {name}')

names = ['Alice', 'Bob']

# Not optional for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(1, initializer=init_pool) as pool:
        # For Linux do this after the pool has been created
        # so that the child processes do not inherit this handler:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)  # Ignore keyboard interrupts
        pool.map(process_name, names)

    ... # Any additional code
    print('I am additional code.')

Prints:
Entering context Alice
Processing Alice
^CExiting context Alice
Exited context Alice
I am additional code.


My bad again, I need the pool.map to stop when I hit ctrl+c and not only stop current threads and keep with remaining taks. I did not think about this edge case where I have only 2 elements and 2 threads.

See update to my answer.

but now I got
Processing Alice
^CExiting context Alice, exc_type = <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>
The pool and all tasks not currently executing have been terminated.
I am additional code.```
`Exited context Alice` is missing...

It's a question of timing. The only way you can kill all the submitted tasks immediately is by issuing a call to terminate on the pool (which occurs when the with block terminates). But because your __exit__ function takes 5 seconds before it prints out the 'exited' message, the process it is running in has terminated before that happens. If you remove the call to time.sleep(5) in __exit__, you will see the 'exited' message. But then the first submitted task ('Alice') will have completed and you might see the start of 'Bob' executing before it is abruptly terminated.

Exactly, and this is what my question is for. I need to gracefully terminate child threads that can take some time to do. But then I want the parent thread to stop when childs are terminated without starting new ones. I am not particularlly searching for a solution that uses pool neither multiprocessing... but if it can, it is cool @Booboo

Just to make sure we are talking about the same thing: There is a difference between multiprocessing and multithreading. You are doing multiprocessing and therefore have child processes (each of which does have a thread, but that is irrelevant). You cannot terminate child threads that are running within the same process, which would be the case if you were running a multithreading pool.

Yup, we're talking about the same thing. I said child thread but meant child process. I though it would be easier to do it using processes but maybe, it is easier to directly manipulate threads. @Booboo
